# wp_categories_dropdown adding default slug names in 'option_none_value' dynamically

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am working on a website and i am little stuck into one situation here below is my working code :-

```
wp_dropdown_categories( 
    array(
        'show_option_none'   => 'All Job-types',
        'option_none_value'  => '',
        'value_field'       => 'slug',
        'taxonomy'          => 'job_listing_type',
        'name'              => 'search_type',
        'orderby'           => 'name',
        'class'             => 'select-on-home',
        'hierarchical'      => true,
        'hide_empty'        => true ,
        'show_option_all'   => esc_html__('','workscout'),
        'echo' => 0
    )
);
```

the problem is 'option_none_value'  => '', i have to manually add the slug names in the 'option_none_value' to display all the  results for the default option (All Job-types) for example :- `'option_none_value'  => 'intership,wfh,full-time',`

is there any way i put dynamic slug name list here of my custom job type??

[job type CPT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YDeNq.png)

[slugs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHvDW.png)

Comment: Are these multiple CPTs having those slugs, or are those the actual post slugs of the posts you have inside a single CPT?

Comment: @CBroe no this is a single custom post type named job listings in which further another option is job types, and as you have asked these are  post slugs of the posts  inside a single CPT job listings>job-types

Comment: @CBroe i just attached the screen shots you make check them

Comment: So it appears you are not actually talking about _post_ slugs, but the slugs of the terms of a specific taxonomy. You can use `get_terms` to get the terms inside a taxonomy. If you set the `fields` parameter to `slugs`, you will get an array of those slugs, and you can then use `implode` to join them with a comma.

Comment: @CBroe do you have any startup code ?

Comment: If you don’t know how the mentioned function works, start by reading up on it. Then try something, and report back here, if you can not get it done on your own.